# Firestore: Check if virtual document exists

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an android app, where users can register. To save user data, I user Firebase Firestore. So, When a user registers, a document with the `FirebaseUser.userId` as id get created.

```
val exampleObject = ExampleObject(exampleData1, exampleData2)
val firestoreUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
firebaseFirestore
   .collection("users")
   .document(firestoreUser.uid)
   .collection("exampleCollection")
   .document("exampleDocument")
   .set(exampleObject)
```

The document that gets created for each user only contains collections, therefore, Firestore does only create a "dummy document". So, how can I check if this document exists or not?

```
firebaseFirestore
    .collection("users")
    .document(firestoreUser.uid)
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { doc->
        if(doc.exists()) {

        } else {

        }
    }
```

This does not work, because it is only a "dummy document", that does not really exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Firestore does only create a "dummy document".

It does **not** create any document. That document does not exist because you didn't create it at all. What you did do, was only to create a subcollection under a document that never existed. In other words, you just reserved an id for a document in a collection and then you created a subcollection under it.

One thing to remember, in Cloud Firestore documents and subcollections don't work like filesystem files and directories. If you create a subcollection under a document, it does **not** implicitly create any parent documents. Subcollections are not tied in any way to a parent document.

So note that there is no physical document at that location but there is other data under the location, which is the `exampleCollection` subcollection. Remember that the "dummy document" that you are talking about becomes a real document only when you write at least a property that can hold a value in it.

So in your case, the following statement:

```
if(doc.exists())
```

Will be always evaluated to `false`.

Comment: Okay, so I just added a property `uid: uid` to each document, which solved the problem. Thank you!